# How to long-click on listview and get position? and delete from the sql

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I can't to get the position of a long-click from a listview but it's possible on single-click

Please help me check what I'm doing wrong?

### My code:

```
adapter=new MoviesAdapter(this,R.layout.layout_row ,listOfmovies);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  //When user will click a row it will launch update Activity
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

    //Identify the movie
    Movies newmovie=adapter.getItem(position);
    Intent updatemovie=new Intent(MainActivity.this,EditMovie.class);
    //will send the rowId number & movie id
    updatemovie.putExtra("rowId", newmovie.getMovieId());
    //will send the data + request code to updateActivity
    startActivityForResult(updatemovie, 0);
  }
});

//SET THE ONLONG CLICK EVENT
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, int i, final long l) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder adChooseAction = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this) ;
    adChooseAction.setTitle("WHAT TO DO?");
    //GO TO EDIT SCREEN
    adChooseAction.setPositiveButton("EDIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Movies editmovie= adapter.getItem(i);
        Intent intentToEditScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this,EditMovie.class);
        intentToEditScreen.putExtra("rowId" ,editmovie.getMovieId());
        startActivityForResult(intentToEditScreen,0);
      }
    });
    //DELETE THE ROW THE USER CHOOSED
    adChooseAction.setNeutralButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        //method to delete movies
        adapter.getItem(i);
        mds.open();
        //will access the MoviesDataSource class to deleteMoviesByRow method
        mds.deleteMovieByRow(i);
        mds.close();
      }
    });
    adChooseAction.show();

    return true;
  }
});
```

As you can see in the short-click it works and brings me to the edit screen with the details of the raw that was clicked but when i try it at the long-click it seems that i cant get the position it points out to this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cage.roll.midleprojectfinal, PID: 20175
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=-3
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
at com.cage.roll.midleprojectfinal.MainActivity$2$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:85)
```

Comment: ddb is right, check his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

redefine the `i` with `position` and it will work

as I can see from your code, you redefined the `i` variable in function `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)`

then, use `position` index variable to access adapter data

Comment: hmm well i changed it to this:
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) 

but it still throw this exeption:
                                                                                 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=27; index=-1

                                                                                         at com.cage.roll.midleprojectfinal.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)


                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

Comment: @rollcage, did you changed also `adapter.getItem(i);` with `adapter.getItem(position);`?

Comment: yes i changed it too
                        Movies editmovie= adapter.getItem(position);

Comment: in `public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id)` try to change `final int position` with `int position`

Comment: but then it will make me do it final because its trying to reach it from inner class

Comment: right. But reading carefully your first comment, the error appears when using the "onClick" listener method, am I right?

Comment: well il try to restrat androidstudio maybe its a problem with him cause now he sends me to line74 and there is no code there its an empty line... and also does making it final is the thing thats breaking it down?
final edit: well like i though it was some apple ghost/voodo trying to mess with me cause now its working great and i didnt chaned anything it styed like this:
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) 

ah and thanks alot :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // do your work here

                return false;
            }
        });
```